# Animation background-image in IE11

Tags: css, animation, background-image, internet-explorer-11

I'm trying to apply css3 animation for button:

```
#mobile-nav-button {
  background-image: url('/images/btn_menu_mobile.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 0 0;
  width: 40px; height: 36px;
  float: left;
  animation: mobile-nav-cue ease-in-out 3s;
  -webkit-animation: mobile-nav-cue ease-in-out 3s;
}
@keyframes mobile-nav-cue {
  from { background-image: url('/images/btn_menu_mobile_cue.png');  }
  to { background-image: url('/images/btn_menu_mobile_active.png'); }
}
@-webkit-keyframes mobile-nav-cue {
  from { background-image: url('/images/btn_menu_mobile_cue.png');  }
  to { background-image: url('/images/btn_menu_mobile_active.png'); }
}
```

And this code works well in all related browsers except IE11.
IE11 just shows first image (defined as common style), and does nothing for animation, when i'm trying to change it via animation.
Any ideas to solve the issue?

P.S. single image with changing background-position is not good solution because it looks not right for animation.

Comment: So you want to swap out the background images every three seconds? Or are you trying to get a fading transition or something as well?

Comment: You cannot animate `background-image`

Comment: This animation occurs during 3 seconds, only once on specific screen width (it's set also within responsive design via media queries). But  I didn't want to show this here because it doesn't matter in context. Animation of background image works and possible, this is just specific case in IE11, and I want find out good solution for it.

Answer (score 0):

Add the other browser prefixes, `@-ms-keyframes`, `@-moz-keyframes`, and `@-o-keyframes`, like you did with webkit to support IE11, Opera, and older FireFoxes because CSS animations do not have standard implementations yet

Comment: No adding prefixes doesn't work. Also common styles like opacity or background-color work well in those @keyframes in IE11. So issue lies deeper.

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-image

> Animatable no

This property cannot be animated. The fact, that it might work in other browsers doesn't mean it should ;).

Comment: The Mozilla link above may have said 'Animatable: No' in 2014, but now it says 'Animatable: discrete', and the current Firefox does allow background-image to be animated (or at least, changed per keyframe), but IE11 and Edge do not, unfortunately.

Comment: The `discrete` means it will change, but will not animate (will just jump, pretty much like css `visibility` attribute). That means that image will be swapped at some point of animation time, but will not transition.